# Mixture of binomial distributions

Tags: integration, normal-distribution, binomial-distribution

I have a population of agents with a single real-valued attribute $x$. Each of them performs $n$ Bernoulli trials with success probability $q(x)$ which depends on their attribute. In particular,
$$
q(x)=a \exp\left(-b x^2\right),
$$
where $a\in(0,1]$ and $b>0$. The distribution that an agent with attribute value $x$ has $k$ successes is thus binomial
$$
P(k\mid x)=\tbinom nk q(x)^k\left(1-q(x)\right)^{n-k}.
$$

I would like to determine the distribution of successes marginalised over the attribute values of the agents, i.e.
$$
P(k)=\int dx P(k\mid x)P(x),
$$
where $P(x)$ is the distribution of agent attributes which I assume to be Gaussian with variance $\Sigma^2$ and mean zero. The full integral thus becomes
\begin{align}
P(k)&=\int dx \, P(k\mid x)P(x)\\
&=\int dx\tbinom nk \left[a \exp\left(-b x^2\right)\right]^k\left[1-a \exp\left(-b x^2\right)\right]^{n-k}\\
&\qquad\times\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\Sigma}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2\Sigma^2}\right).
\end{align}

It's causing me a bit of a headache. I have made the following attempts:

- Expand the term $(1-q(x))^{n-k}$ using the binomial theorem but the result is an alternating series and is numerically very badly behaved.
- Expand the term $(1-q(x))^{n-k}$ to first order in $q(x)$ because I know that $q$ is small. However, that approach is also plagued by numerical problems.
- Approximate the binomial distribution with the Poisson distribution (I know that $n$ is large) but that doesn't simplify the integration. Further approximating by a Gaussian didn't help me either.

Comment: If your integral is to make sense, then $P(x)$ would have to be a probability _density_.  I'd have said that explicitly.  But you also use $P(k)$ apparently for the marginal probability that the number of successes is $k$.  So you're using the same symbol, $P$, for two different functions.  Is $P(3)$ to be the value of the normal (or "Gaussian") probability density at $3$, or is it the marginal probability that the number of successes is $3$?  One could use $P_X$ and $P_K$ to refer respectively to the density of a normally distributed random variable $X$ and the probability mass function of...

Comment: ...a discrete random variable $K$, and then the meaning of $P_K(3)$ and $P_X(3)$ would be clear and explicit. (I prefer the more usual convention of lower-case $f$ for the density or mass function, capital $F$ for the cumulative distribution function, and $P(A)$ for probability of an event $A$.) ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: So $K\mid X\sim\mathrm{Binomial}(a\exp(-bX^2))$ and $X\sim N(0,\Sigma^2)$ and you seek the marginal distribution of $K$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: The Poisson distribution is not a good approximation of the binomial distribution unless the expected value is small compared to $n$.  That certainly won't happen if $x$ is near $0$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Yes, the notation could be more rigorous. As you mentioned in your third comment, I seek the marginal distribution of $K$. I assume that $a$ is sufficiently small for the Poisson distribution to be a good approximation irrespective of $x$. Unfortunately, the approximation does not help with the integral.